# Controlling the Data of a Database Docker Container

Tags: database, docker

I'm new to Docker and containers in general, and was wondering if:

1. this approach is possible, and
2. are there better/more-proven approaches

[image: overview diagram]

I have a "Command Central" web app that's responsible for maintaining the data for multiple teams. The teams will each work with their own containers, which come in pairs; one web app and one database.

I'd ideally like to, from the "Command Central" web app, generate the data that a given Database container will use. Should it be as simple as an export of the data from the "Command Central" app?

Answer (score 0):

You can adopt many strategies to solve that:

1) Use a host volume shared between Command Central and yours containers.

1.1) Using host file system
1.2) Using distributed file system
1.3) tagging and consuming another data only container.

2) Connecting on container to perform any operation
2.1) FTP, WEBDAV, SAMBA or other protocol to get files
2.2) Connect using own SQL protocol of your db mapping the connection port or using docker networking.

You have some options to perform that, i just list 2 or 3 cases in 2 ways, we have many others.